# My Android App can only read the first line of file under directory /proc

Tags: java, android, linux

As the subject, I used below line to read content of proc file /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats, only the first line was read into my program.

```
List<String> stdout = Shell.SH.run("cat /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats");
```

I also attempted some conventional ways to read the file, they can't work. However, when I run the command `run-as my_app_name "cat /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats` in Shell, the whole file can be displayed. Any clue for this problem?

BTW, "Usage Access" permission is granted to the App, and my mobile is OnePlus3T with Android 6.0.1, and the system has been rooted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying the first line of the code provided isn't working?

You can try the following below if that is what you want to achieve, when you referring to command term works but line code doesn't.

```
private static final String TAG = "Yo! I got an error";

   public static List<Process> getMyInfo() {
        List<Process> myData = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> stdout = Shell.SH.run("cat /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats");
        for (String line : stdout) {
            try {
                myData.add(new Process(line));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "This line ain't working" + line);
            }
        }
        return muData;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, the first line of the code can't work. You code still can't work on my mobile ..

Answer (score 1):

Find the answer ^_^

Grant the permission "READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" to the APP, add the line in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```